# Java 9+ change default class loading with modules

Tags: java, classloader, java-9

I tried to change the default classloader in a modular Java9+ project but was unable to make it work. If I use traditional non modular main class, then the classloader is used :

```
$ java -Djava.system.class.loader="CustomLoader" test.MainClass
```

I'll then have messages from several overriden methods in my custom classloader.

but if I used a module schema like :

```
$ java -Djava.system.class.loader="CustomLoader" -p ... -m module/test.MainClass
```

then nothing happens, except the message from the constructor with the `delegate argument. The loading takes place (with the standard default I presume) and the application runs correctly.

The `CustomLoader` I used is:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
  
  public CustomClassLoader() {
    System.out.println("empty");
  }
  public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader delegate) {
    super(delegate);
    System.out.println("delegate");
  }
  public CustomClassLoader(String name,ClassLoader delegate) {
    super(delegate);
    System.out.println("name delegate");
  }
  
  @Override
  protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println(getParent());
    System.out.println("Find "+name);
    return super.findClass(name);
  }
  @Override
  protected Class<?> findClass(String module,String name) {
    System.out.println("Find "+module+" : "+name);
    return super.findClass(module,name);
  }
  @Override
  protected String findLibrary(String name) {
    System.out.println("Find Library "+name);
    return super.findLibrary(name);
  }
  @Override
  public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException { 
    System.out.println("Loading "+name);
    return super.loadClass(name);
  }
  @Override
  public Class<?> loadClass(String name,boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
   
    System.out.println("Loading "+name);
    return super.loadClass(name,resolve);
    
  }
}
```

Then how to short circuit the classloading in a Java9+ modular project?

Comment: This doesn’t work. This anachronistic feature of setting a custom system class loader doesn’t affect module loading. But what do you want to achieve? “short circuit the classloading” contradicts the fact that you were adding another detour, if it worked.

Comment: @Holger I want to control the loading of classes from the start (except systems classes)... Is it forbidden? I can control it for every classe dynamically loaded, so why wouldn't it be possible to make it from the beginning? Why modules would change the needed?

Comment: What do you want to control?

Comment: @Holger for example, use a different classloader for each module, so that package collision will not appear. Or boot a java app from network (not lad classes and then load, but directly load classes from network). Log all loaded classes, etc.

Comment: Most of these examples do not work by replacing the system class loader and do not actually need replacing the system class loader. When you want to load a module through a different class loader, just do that. Create a new class loader and add it together with its associated module(s) to the environment. When you want to log class loading, just use the builtin class logging feature.

Comment: @Holger I want to load all classes from the beginning with a custom one. I know how to load classes with a custom one during runtime. I just want to start a custom load form the beginning, is this possible? If yes, may I have an hint? *Create a new class loader and add it together with its associated module(s) to the environment. * What does means?

Comment: “all classes from the beginning” doesn’t work anyway, as at least your custom class loader can’t get loaded by your custom loader. There is is no difference to having a startup class setting up the actual application modules. I was thinking about `ModuleLayer.defineModulesWithOneLoader`, but now I realize that this still creates a new class loader for the actual loading of module classes, in other words, there is no custom class loader possible. But anyway, if you want to decorate/customize the actual loading, a custom `ModuleReader` would do.